# Silverlight toolkit themes override styles?

Tags: silverlight, themes, styles

I have a Silverlight app that has a bunch of styles that are referenced everywhere in various controls...etc.
If I apply one of the default silverlight.toolkit.themes to the app will these styles be overridden by the them (assuming the theme affects whatever the styles are applied to)?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i upgraded to sl 4.0. so the theme/stlyes are all implicit. case closed.